# Does a line or a plane considered a vector-space, or a vector-sub-space?

Tags: linear-algebra

For example in $\mathbb{R}^3$ :
$$
    L = k(1,2,3) + (4,5,6)
$$
$$
    P_1 = u(1,1,-1) + v(3,2,-1) + (7,8,9)
$$
$$
    P_2 = u(1,1,-1) + v(3,2,-1) + (8,9,10)
$$
Are these considered vector spaces, or at least sub spaces of $\mathbb{R}^3$?

if so then what is the dimension of$ (P_1 + P_2)$ ?

Comment: These are called *affine* subspaces. They are not vector subspaces because they do not contain the origin.

Comment: These are *affine* subspaces of $\mathbf R^3$, i.e., roughly, translates of vector subspaces. Don't forget a vector subspace must contain the origin.

Comment: What do you means for $P_1+P_2$?

Comment: @EmilioNovati it means Union . Or maby span(P1 U P2) I'm not too sure what i mean honestly... :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments $L$, $P_1$ and $P-2$ are affine subspaces of the affine space $\mathbb{R}^3$ and they are. by themself, affine spaces. With a translation of the origin that transform these line and planes to line and planes passing thorough the origin tey become vector spaces.

The union of $P-1$ and $P-2$ (if this means $P_1+P_2$) is not a space (affine or vector) since it not contains all the linear combination of the two space ( note that the twospaces are parallel).

As far as I know ( but maybe I'm wrong), the span of the union is not a so well defined thing in affine geometry. But if you intend the affine space generated by affine transformations of all elements in the two planes then this is an affine space that coincide with $\mathbb{R}^3$.